# Why my toString JOptionPane not showing?

Tags: sql, joptionpane

this code gives me an error after inserting the values of radius.

> "Exception in thread "main"
>   java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double"

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class TestCircle {

public static void main(String[]args) 
{
String rad1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter circle 1 radius: \n");
Circle circle1 = new Circle();
circle1.setRadius(Integer.parseInt(rad1));

String rad2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter circle 2 radius: \n");   

Circle circle2 = new Circle(Integer.parseInt(rad2));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,circle1.toString());
}


  public String toString()
{   return          String.format("Radius:%d\nDiameter:%d\nCircumference:%.2f\nArea%.2f\n",getRadius(),circumference(),area());
}
```

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace and the related code

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4045)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Formatter.java:2748)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2702)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2488)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2423)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2792)
 at Circle.toString(Circle.java:52)
 at TestCircle.main(TestCircle.java:21)

Comment: Add the code of `Circle.toString` to your question using the edit function. not as comment

Answer (score 0):

Your methods `circumference()` or `area()` don't return a double value.

Answer (score 0):

My toString method was missing diameter()...once included that it worked perfectly.

```
public String toString()
{
 return String.format("Radius:%d\nDiameter:%d\nCircumference:%.2f\nArea%.2f\n",  getRadius(),diameter(), circumference(), area());
}
```